# I am trying to position a multi-column bootstrap dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

http://web.patrick-diaz.com/test/

I am trying to position a dropdown menu item that has 4 columns in it (bootstrap version 3.3).

If you hover over "locations", you will see it pops out way to the left. In different sizes of screens, it either pops out to the left or to the right, but always clipped by the screen.

I would like it to appear somewhat centered.  Can somebody help me figure out what to adjust or add to CSS?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is the navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top navbar-transparent" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#custom-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="custom-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Locations</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
                      <li>
                          <div class="row" style="width: 900px; padding:25px;">

                              <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-3">
                                  <li><h5 class="text-uppercase">California</h5></li>
                                  <li><h6 class="text-uppercase">Orange County</h5></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Huntington Beach</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Irvine</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Yorba Linda</a></li>
                                  <br/>
                                  <li><h6 class="text-uppercase">San Diego County</h5></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Carlsbad</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Sorrento Valley</a></li>

                              </ul>

                              <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-3">
                                <br/>
                                <li><h6 class="text-uppercase">San Gabriel Valley</h5></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Alhambra @ LA Fitness</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Arcadia @ LA Fitness</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Pasadena</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sierra Madre</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">West Covina @ LA Fitness</a></li>
                                <br/>
                                <li><h6 class="text-uppercase">LA County</h5></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Beverly Hills</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Torrance</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Rancho Palos Verdes</a></li>


                              </ul>
                              <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-3">
                                <br/>
                                <li><h6 class="text-uppercase">Silicone Valley</h5></li>
                                <li><a href="#">San Jose</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sunnyvalle @ City Sports Club</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Almaden @ City Sports Club</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">North San Jose @ City Sports Club</a></li>
                                <br/>
                                <li><h6 class="text-uppercase">Almeda County</h5></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Hayward @ City Sports Club</a></li>
                                <br/>
                                <li><h6 class="text-uppercase">San Francisco</h5></li>
                                <li><a href="#">20th Avenue @ City Sports Club</a></li>
                              </ul>

                              <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-3">
                                <h5 class="text-uppercase">Find a Location</h5>
                                <p>Not sure which location is closest to you? Enter your zip code in the field below and we'll give you a list of facilities closest to you!</p>
                                <form>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter your zip code">
                                  </div>
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                </form>

                              </ul>
                          </div>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Lessons</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="login_register.html">Private</a></li>
                  <li><a href="faq.html">Semi Private</a></li>
                  <li><a href="404.html">Stroke Clinic</a></li>
                  <li><a href="404.html">Parent & Me</a></li>
                  <li><a href="404.html">Adult Lessons</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Programs</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Swim Competition</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Swim Teams</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Swim Camp</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Family Swim Night</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Junior Lifeguard Prep Cours</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dives & Turns Clinic</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Lifesaving / Swimming Merit Badges</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Waterpolo Conditioning Clinics</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Lap Swims</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Water Aerobics</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Girl Scout Program</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Aquanaut / Swimming Activity Badges</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a  href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">FAQ</a></li>
              <li><a  href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Parties</a></li>
              <li><a  href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Contact</a></li>

              <li><button class="btn btn-l btn-circle btn-xs nav-reg-btn" type="submit" >Register / Sign In</button>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-left {
left: 0;
position: absolute;
transform: translate(50%); }
```

Let me know if this helps and if that is what you meant.

EDIT:

It might be the media queries overwriting certain CSS rules. Check your media queries at @991px and @776px to see what is changing. I'm eating, will get back to you afterwards :).

Comment: Yes this fixed my issue, thank you very much. It does open up another issue though, how can I do this in normal desktop monitors, but if it gets smaller, all the sudden it happens again. Do I need to adjust where the style is placed? It seems to break the nav in mobile. Thanks for your help.